# What is a "Physically Stored Sequence" in Python?

Tags: python, sequence

I am currently reading Learning Python, 5th Edition - by Mark Lutz and have come across the phrase "Physically Stored Sequence".

From what I've learnt so far, a sequence is an object that contains items that can be indexed in sequential order from left to right e.g. Strings, Tuples and Lists.

So in regards to a "Physically Stored Sequence", would that be a Sequence that is referenced by a variable for use later on in a program? Or am not getting it?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: This phrase [appears](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-14/iterators-a-first-look) to be used to distinguish between actual sequence objects (like `list`, `tuple`, etc.) and things that behave like them, i.e. other objects that implement the *iteration protocol* (`__next__`, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Physically Stored Sequence is best explained by contrast.  It is one type of "iterable" with the main example of the other type being a "generator."

A generator is an iterable, meaning you can iterate over it as in a "for" loop, but it does not actually store anything--it merely spits out values when requested.  Examples of this would be a pseudo-random number generator, the whole `itertools` package, or any function you write yourself using `yield`.  Those sorts of things can be the subject of a "for" loop but do not actually "contain" any data.

A physically stored sequence then is an iterable which does contain its data.  Examples include most data structures in Python, like lists.  It doesn't matter in the Python parlance if the items in the sequence have any particular reference count or anything like that (e.g. the `None` object exists only once in Python, so `[None, None]` does not exactly "store" it twice).

A key feature of physically stored sequences is that you can usually iterate over them multiple times, and sometimes get items other than the "first" one (the one any iterable gives you when you call `next()` on it).

All that said, this phrase is not very common--certainly not something you'd expect to see or use as a workaday Python programmer.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thanks you.